# How do I update an element class based on a separate element's active class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I am trying to reproduce the effect on Chaptr's website, about half way down the page, where scrolling past a list elements changes the class of separate elements that are sticky/fixed. Example here: https://chaptr.studio/, "Brand, Creative, Code, Growth," section.

I've managed to get part of the effect to work with the following code, although it isn't the cleanest. Is there anyway I could get the left hand list of elements "Investments, Education, Mentoring" to match what is happening with the non-sticky list.

```
const halfWindow = (window.innerHeight / 2) - 50
const listItems = document.querySelectorAll('.scroll-item')

const firstItem = listItems[0]
const lastItem = listItems[listItems.length - 1]

const updateSection = () => {
  const pixels = window.pageYOffset

  listItems.forEach(item => {

    // find the position of each item
    const itemTop = item.offsetTop - pixels
    const itemBottom = (item.offsetTop + item.offsetHeight) - pixels

    // first item top
    const firstItemTop = firstItem.offsetTop - pixels
    const firstItemBottom = (firstItem.offsetTop + firstItem.offsetHeight) - pixels

    // target the first item in the array
    if (firstItemBottom <= halfWindow) {
      firstItem.classList.remove('active')
      firstItem.classList.remove('current')
    } else if (firstItemBottom >= halfWindow) {
      firstItem.classList.add('current')
    }

    // working sort of - clean up
    if ((itemTop <= halfWindow) && (itemBottom <= halfWindow)) {
      item.classList.remove('active')   
      if (item === lastItem) {
        item.classList.add('current')
      }
    } else if ((itemTop <= halfWindow) && (itemBottom >= halfWindow)) {
      item.classList.add('active')
      item.classList.remove('current')
    } else {
      item.classList.remove('active')
    }

  })
}

document.addEventListener("scroll", updateSection)
```

Here is a codepen example:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gVOZzp?

The main bit I need to figure out is how to match the left hand list items to active, when each list item on the right becomes "active".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I set up the variable like Azametzin said with:

```
const innerItems = document.querySelectorAll('.sticky-inner li')
```

Then using `classList.contains` and `getAttribute`, compared both lists – checking to see if they matched. See code below:

```
const updateSectionHeadings = () => {

  listItems.forEach(item => {

    // if the item has the active or current class
    if (item.classList.contains('active') || item.classList.contains('current')) {

      // set itemData to the data attribute's value
      let itemData = item.getAttribute('data-name')

      // loop through the section list
      innerItems.forEach(innerItem => {
        // set innerItemData to the data attribute's value
        let innerItemData = innerItem.getAttribute('data-name')

        if (itemData !== innerItemData) {
          // if itemData is not the same as innerItemData
          innerItem.classList.remove('active')
        } else if (itemData === innerItemData) {
          // if itemData is the same as innerItemData
          innerItem.classList.add('active')
        }

      })

    }

  })

}

document.addEventListener("scroll", updateSectionHeadings)
window.addEventListener("resize", updateSectionHeadings)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is like this. First, select all inner items to work with storing them in a `global variable`:

```
const innerItems = document.querySelectorAll('.sticky-inner li');
```

Then, you can add this in the end of `updateSection` `function`:

```
  if (document.querySelector('.sticky-inner .active')) {
    document.querySelector('.sticky-inner .active').classList.remove('active');
  }
  if (listItems[0].classList.contains('active')) {
    innerItems[0].classList.add('active');
  } else if (listItems[1].classList.contains('active')) {
    innerItems[1].classList.add('active');
  } else if (listItems[2].classList.contains('active')) {
    innerItems[2].classList.add('active');
  }
```

It will always compare both hands to match them and add/remove the `active` `class`.

Comment: Thanks very much Azametzin, this got me going and testing other methods.